# Delete a key from a hash

Tags: ruby, jekyll, algolia

I do not know Ruby at all but I am trying to extend [this Jekyll plugin](https://github.com/algolia/jekyll-algolia/issues/71). The author mentions to just delete the key from the record. I've tried using the `delete` function but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
module Jekyll
  module Algolia
   module Hooks
     def self.before_indexing_each(record, node, context)
      record.delete(":gallery")
      record
     end
   end
  end
end
```

I am sure I am missing something very simple here but any ideas would be great. The hash looks like the following:

```
{:html=>"<p>Captain Brieux is a character in the 1974 film, The Island at the Top of World. Portrayed by Jacques Marin, he is a French inventor who pilots an expedition in a French dirigible name the Hyperion (a model can be found at Disneyland Paris).</p>", :content=>"Captain Brieux is a character in the 1974 film, The Island at the Top of World. Portrayed by Jacques Marin, he is a French inventor who pilots an expedition in a French dirigible name the Hyperion (a model can be found at Disneyland Paris).", :headings=>[], :custom_ranking=>{:position=>0, :heading=>100}, :title=>"Captain Brieux", :membership=>"Unconfirmed", :portrait=>"/gallery/members/captain-brieux/portrait.jpg", :attractions=>["_attractions/skipper-canteen.md"], :parks=>["Magic Kingdom", "Disneyland Paris"], :gallery=>[], :collection=>"members", :tags=>[], :categories=>[], :excerpt_html=>"<p>Captain Brieux is a character in the 1974 film, The Island at the Top of World. Portrayed by Jacques Marin, he is a French inventor who pilots an expedition in a French dirigible name the Hyperion (a model can be found at Disneyland Paris).</p>", :excerpt_text=>"Captain Brieux is a character in the 1974 film, The Island at the Top of World. Portrayed by Jacques Marin, he is a French inventor who pilots an expedition in a French dirigible name the Hyperion (a model can be found at Disneyland Paris).", :slug=>"captain-brieux", :type=>"document", :url=>"/sea/members/captain-brieux"}
```

Comment: The key is a symbol, try that way `(record.delete(:gallery))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem that you are having in your code is that you are sending the symbol as string, just remove "" from the delete param

```
module Jekyll
  module Algolia
   module Hooks
     def self.before_indexing_each(record, node, context)
      record.delete(:gallery)
      record
     end
   end
  end
end
```